# How to make a custom slider switch the pictures programmatically

Tags: jquery

I saw in the jQuery documentation that you can start a function after a interval so that's what i tried. webstorm doesn't give me any errors but it doesn't work.

```
setInterval(function (slider2js) {
    $("#foto31").hide("3000");
    console.log("1");
}, 2000,
    (function () {
        console.log("yay");
        $("#foto32").hide("3000")
    }), 2000,
    (function () {
        console.log("kaas");
        $("#foto31").show();
        $("#foto32").show();
    })
);
```

in the console it just says "1" over and over and it wont reach the other code.

thanks in advance

edit just to clarify: the question is ow do i make all of the code run after one another

Comment: you probably miss a parenthesys in the last line of your code btw

Answer (score 0):

slick slider will give you way better examples for your sliders.

Please check @http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ to check examples.

Thanks!